# Difficulty in getting current session in hibernate framework in java

Tags: java, hibernate

I am facing problem in getting the currentsession by using the following statement-

> Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

My HibernateUtil class has the following code-

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {

            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {

            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
```

And my hibernate.cfg.xml file is as follows-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE
 hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration
 DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
 <hibernate-configuration>   <session-factory>
     <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:anu</property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.username">admin</property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.password">abc</property>
     <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
     <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
     <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

     <mapping resource="hbm/Userinfo.hbm.xml"/>
     <mapping/>   </session-factory> </hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing? If you are getting a compile/runtime error please post it

Comment: the Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession(); statement is not throwing any exception. I am calling it from a Servlet and the servlet just stops when it encounters this statement.

Comment: This may be the first time it is trying to open a connection to the database.  Is it possible your database has some kind of maxConnections property or something which is blocking Hibernate when it tries to open a connection?

Comment: If there's no exception and you're sure you haven't somehow ignored/hidden the exception, then you are most likely either blocked like @Pace suggested or you've run into a deadlock somehow. You should be able to debug with your IDE and pause the thread to see where exactly it is "stopped".

Comment: do you have the oracle server running in your local machine (@ localhost:1521)? If so, you can examine the V$Session to see the connection is really getting established at all.

Comment: The same problem is coming up with other projects using other databases too.

Comment: In v$session, status is inactive for that process. I also tested retrieval of rows using HQL editor in the IDE and it is working fine

Comment: Thank you guys. I got what the problem was. I gave the POJO class name wrong 'Userinfo' instead of 'UserInfo'.